# Exclude databases from "database, table, procedure" search in DataGrip

Tags: datagrip

Is there any way to limit the search for a table using Cmd+O ("database, table, procedure" search in DataGrip) to the current schema, open databases, or in some other way?

I have many databases with the same structure for different envs, and it is difficult to use the search because I need to go through the list of found tables to choose the one I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am Max from DataGrip. There is no such possibility now. But we're totally agree that current implementation is inconvenient. We have been discussing this while creating our roadmap for 2018, and I hope we'll create an easy way to define various scopes in this search.

Comment: Could you share a link to a ticket in YouTrack for that? It will help other to track the progress and vote.

Comment: @SerhiyYakovyn well, it didn't exist. I've created it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5592